# PowerPivot DAX - Creating column based on most common value in another column

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have a table in my Power Pivot model that includes customer IDs, account IDs, and sales for a bunch of transactions. The problem is that some account IDs are missing.

For any record with a missing account ID, I want to populate it with the most common account ID for the customer (based on sales).

| Cust_ID | Acct_ID | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 225 | ABC | 10 |
| 225 | ABC | 50 |
| 225 | DEF | 0 |
| 225 |  | 10 |
| 225 |  | 20 |
| 588 | XYZ | 500 |

So for Customer 225, the most common Account ID (based on sales) is ABC. I'd want to add a column like this.

| Cust_ID | Acct_ID | Sales | Final_Acct_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 225 | ABC | 10 | ABC |
| 225 | ABC | 50 | ABC |
| 225 | DEF | 0 | ABC |
| 225 |  | 10 | ABC |
| 225 |  | 20 | ABC |
| 588 | XYZ | 500 | XYZ |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Final_Acct_ID = 
VAR tbl = 
CALCULATETABLE(
FILTER(
    ADDCOLUMNS(  
        SUMMARIZE( 'Table1', 'Table1'[Cust_ID], 'Table1'[Acct_ID]), 
        "@count",
        CALCULATE( COUNT('Table1'[Acct_ID])) 
    ), 
    'Table1'[Acct_ID] <> BLANK()
),

ALLEXCEPT('Table1','Table1'[Cust_ID]))

RETURN 

MAXX(TOPN(1,tbl,[@count]), 'Table1'[Acct_ID])
```

[image]

Comment: COUNT('Table1'[Acct_ID]) or SUM('Table1'[Sales]) ?

Comment: Possibly yes now that I have re-read the requirements. Depends on interpretation of what OP has written.